# How to authenticate user for a specific object rather than whole class in django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on making an app to add clubs in website. This is my model.py file

```
from django.db import models
from stdimage import StdImageField
# Create your models here.


class Club(models.Model):
    ClubName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ClubLogo = StdImageField(upload_to='club_logo', variations={'thumbnail':(150, 200, True)})
    ClubDetails = models.TextField()
    ClubStartDate = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ClubName

class Notice(models.Model):
    NOTICE = 'NOTICE'
    UPDATES = 'UPDATES'
    EVENTS = 'EVENTS'

    NOTICE_IN_CHOICES = (
        (NOTICE, 'Notice'),
        (UPDATES, 'Updates'),
        (EVENTS, 'Events'),)

    NoticeType = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=NOTICE_IN_CHOICES, default=NOTICE)
    NoticeTag = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    NoticeStartDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    NoticeEndDate = models.DateField()
    NoticeFile = models.FileField(default='#', upload_to='notice/%Y/%m/%d')
    NoticeContent = models.TextField(default='NA')
    NoticeClub = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.NoticeTag

class Members(models.Model):
    MemeberName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    MemberImage = StdImageField(upload_to='member_photo', variations={'thumbnail':(150, 120, True)})
    MemberEmail = models.EmailField()
    MemberClub = models.ForeignKey(Club)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.MemeberName
```

Now when i am making users via django's inbuilt admin panel i have option to give permission to users to change member of any club but i want to give access to change members of only that particular club which he is member of. 
As you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCrm3.png) that all club are in dropdown option when someone who has access to add notices adding otices. But instead of that i want only one option in the dropdown for the useradmin to which he is associated.

this is my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from club.models import Club, Members, Notice

admin.site.register(Club),
admin.site.register(Members),
admin.site.register(Notice),
```

Comment: You should show your admin file.

Comment: It sounds as you have re-purposed django admin for use as your main website. That's not what it's meant for.

Comment: i have added admin.py file. @MosesKoledoye

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with which many users have been struggling with.

I have been using couple of external packages, and couple of self made solutions. But the best one I have found so far is [Django Guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) It's an implementation of per object permission .This means you can manage users and permissions to which they have access to.

Comment: In which class do i have to add the Meta permisiion class for django-guardian?